# Material ui replace TextField functionality with autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield

Here is a simple example of the code. There is a list of countries, which I am mapping over and displaying the options inside of the TextField component, so the user can select.  TextField is great, but it is missing the search functionality, so I decided to switch to Autocomplete. But when it comes to controlled autocomplete component, there are some issues. I will attach the code with TextField, and after with Autocomplete.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

const App = () => {
  const [branch, setBranch] = useState("us");

  const countries = [
    { id: 1, name: "United States", iso_a2: "us" },
    { id: 2, name: "France", iso_a2: "fr" },
    { id: 3, name: "Brasil", iso_a2: "br" }
  ];

  return (
    <TextField
      helperText="Branch"
      onChange={(e) => setBranch(e.target.value)}
      select
      value={branch}
      variant="outlined"
    >
      {countries.map(({ id, name, iso_a2 }) => (
        <MenuItem key={id} value={iso_a2}>
          {name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Here is the code which works fine with TextField. I tried to do as it was described in the documentation, but I am getting error in the console every time. Has anybody faced the same problem?
If yes, or if you could solve it please help :)

Comment: You're not showing us your `Autocomplete` code and you haven't told us what error you're getting.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pare-157l5?file=/src/App.js 

Here is the piece of code, I can't include all my project here, it is very huge with lots of files. 

The error occurs when I try to send the selected data to backend. My question is, if anybody else had issue with this component from Material UI.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflating strings and objects between `Autocomplete` and `Textfield` components. I've forked your codesandbox (and deleted the Textfield part to prevent errors) to show you a working example based on your code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-stallman-syjs9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to use it in my code, and if it works I will let you know :) 

I just let the textfield be here so you can see them side by side.